# Can ROS 2 services and actions span subnets?

Tags: ros2, dds, networking

In ROS 2, can services and actions span subnets using TCP as oppose to topics which only use UDP? Also for DDS I found,

> This means that all DDS specific APIs and message definitions would need to be hidden. DDS provides discovery, message definition, message serialization, and publish-subscribe transport. Therefore, DDS would provide discovery, publish-subscribe transport, and at least the underlying message serialization for ROS.

Does that mean that DDS only works with UDP? Ultimately I want to know if I can send data from one IP network to another.

Answer (score 1):

I've researched and experimented with this a bit trying to send ROS2 messages between subnets on separate vehicles.   The problem I always ran into was multicast topic discovery.  This is because multicasting (used in topic discovery) is not supported between subnets on many network setups.

DDS discovery servers provide a way to discover topics using TCP (much like ROS1 master). Any node looking for a topic/service/action will ask the server where to find it using TCP rather than waiting for the information through multicast.

Basically, if you can ping the DDS discovery server from your different subsets you should get full discovery functionality.

You can find information on how to set it up here:   https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Advanced/Discovery-Server/Discovery-Server.html